# Persistence postprocessing in three.js with 2 renderTargets

Tags: three.js, glsl, post-processing

I am trying to implement [this effect](https://youtu.be/rfQ8rKGTVlg?t=32m1s). As it is explained in the video, I have to make 2 extra renderTargets, blend the current image with renderTarget #1 into renderTarget #2, but I am having difficulties with implementing it in three.js. You can check my code here

```js
let w = window.innerWidth
let h = window.innerHeight

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, w / h, 0.1, 1000)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
const clock = new THREE.Clock()

let frontBuffer = createRenderTarget()
let backBuffer  = frontBuffer.clone()
let readBuffer  = frontBuffer
let writeBuffer = backBuffer

const renderScene = new THREE.Scene()
const renderCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-w / 2, w / 2, -h / 2, h / 2, -1000, 1000)
const renderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: { value: writeBuffer.texture }
  },
  vertexShader: `
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main () {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

      vUv = uv;
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main () {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(tDiffuse, vUv);
    }
  `
})
const renderMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(w, h),
  renderMaterial
)
renderMesh.rotation.x += Math.PI
renderScene.add(renderMesh)
  
let timeElapsed = 0
let shape

setMainScene()
renderFrame()

function createRenderTarget () {
  let type = THREE.FloatType
  if( renderer.extensions.get( 'OES_texture_float_linear' ) === null ) type = THREE.HalfFloatType

  let renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 1, 1, {
    type,
    wrapS: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    wrapT: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    stencilBuffer: false,
    depthBuffer: true
  })
  
  renderTarget.texture.generateMipmaps = false
  renderTarget.setSize(w, h)

  return renderTarget
}

function swapBuffers () {
  if (readBuffer === frontBuffer) {
    readBuffer  = backBuffer
    writeBuffer = frontBuffer
  } else {
    readBuffer  = frontBuffer
    writeBuffer = backBuffer
  }
}

function setMainScene () {
  renderer.setSize(w, h)
  renderer.setClearColor(0x111111)
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  camera.position.set(0, 20, 100)
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3())

  shape = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(10, 20, 20),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000 })
  )
  scene.add(shape)
}

function renderFrame () {
  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame)

  renderer.render(scene, camera, writeBuffer)
  renderer.render(renderScene, renderCamera)
  swapBuffers()
  
  timeElapsed += clock.getDelta()
  
  shape.position.x = Math.sin(timeElapsed) * 20.0
  shape.position.y = Math.cos(timeElapsed * Math.PI) * 20.0
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
```

First, I create my two extra framebuffers:

```
let frontBuffer = createRenderTarget()
let backBuffer  = frontBuffer.clone()
let readBuffer  = frontBuffer
let writeBuffer = backBuffer

function createRenderTarget () {
  let type = THREE.FloatType
  if( renderer.extensions.get( 'OES_texture_float_linear' ) === null ) type = THREE.HalfFloatType

  let renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 1, 1, {
    type,
    wrapS: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    wrapT: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    stencilBuffer: false,
    depthBuffer: true
  })

  renderTarget.texture.generateMipmaps = false
  renderTarget.setSize(w, h)

  return renderTarget
}
```

Then I create an extra scene, a plane (to which I will render my main scene) covering the screen and a orthographic camera. I pass the result image of the main scene render as a uniform to my post-processing plane:

```
const renderScene = new THREE.Scene()
const renderCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-w / 2, w / 2, -h / 2, h / 2, -1000, 1000)
const renderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: { value: writeBuffer.texture }
  },
  vertexShader: `
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main () {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

      vUv = uv;
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main () {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(tDiffuse, vUv);
    }
  `
})
```

Finally, in my animation loop, I first render the main scene to the current fbo and then render my post-processing plane and I swap my buffers:

```
function swapBuffers () {
  if (readBuffer === frontBuffer) {
    readBuffer  = backBuffer
    writeBuffer = frontBuffer
  } else {
    readBuffer  = frontBuffer
    writeBuffer = backBuffer
  }
}

function renderFrame () {
  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame)

  renderer.render(scene, camera, writeBuffer)
  renderer.render(renderScene, renderCamera)
  swapBuffers()

  timeElapsed += clock.getDelta()

  shape.position.x = Math.sin(timeElapsed) * 20.0
  shape.position.y = Math.cos(timeElapsed * Math.PI) * 20.0
}
```

This is all fine and good and I can see my main scene render shown on the post-processing plane, but I can't understand how to blend it with the previous framebuffer. I guess I am very wrong in my current implementation, but information is scarce and I simply can't wrap my head around how to achieve this blending.

I tried passing both of my buffers as textures and then blending between them in GLSL, like this:

```
// js
uniforms: {
    tDiffuse1: { value: writeBuffer.texture },
    tDiffuse2: { value: readBuffer.texture }
  }

// glsl
gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(tDiffuse1, vUv), texture2D(tDiffuse2, vUv), 0.5);
```

But visually I don't see any blending going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 3 render targets. Let's call them `sceneTarget`, `previousTarget`, `resultTarget`

Step 1: Render your scene to the `sceneTarget`.

You now have your scene in `sceneTarget.texture`

Step 2: Blend `sceneTarget.texture` with `previousTarget.texture` into `resultTarget`

This one you need 2 textures as input like you mentioned at the bottom of your question. You need to update the material uniforms to use the correct textures every frame

```
renderMaterial.uniforms.tDiffuse1.value = previousTarget.texture;
renderMaterial.uniforms.tDiffuse2.value = sceneTarget.texture;
```

Now you have a blended result in `resultTarget.texture`

Step 3: render `resultTarget.texture` to the canvas.

Now you can actually see the result.

Step 4: swap `resultTarget` and `previousTarget`

```js
let w = window.innerWidth
let h = window.innerHeight

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, w / h, 0.1, 1000)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
const clock = new THREE.Clock()

let sceneTarget = createRenderTarget()
let previousTarget  = sceneTarget.clone();
let resultTarget  = sceneTarget.clone();

const blendScene = new THREE.Scene();
const blendCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2, -1000, 1000);
const blendMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse1: { value: previousTarget.texture },
    tDiffuse2: { value: sceneTarget.texture },
  },
  vertexShader: `
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main () {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

      vUv = uv;
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform sampler2D tDiffuse1;
    uniform sampler2D tDiffuse2;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main () {
      gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(tDiffuse1, vUv), texture2D(tDiffuse2, vUv), 0.25);
    }
  `,
});
const blendMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(w, h),
  blendMaterial
);
blendMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI;
blendScene.add(blendMesh);

const resultScene = new THREE.Scene();
const resultCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2, -1000, 1000);
const resultMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: resultTarget.texture,
});
const resultMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(w, h),
  resultMaterial
);
resultMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI;
resultScene.add(resultMesh);

let shape

setMainScene()
renderFrame(0)

function createRenderTarget () {
  let type = THREE.FloatType
  if( renderer.extensions.get( 'OES_texture_float_linear' ) === null ) type = THREE.HalfFloatType

  let renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 1, 1, {
    type,
    wrapS: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    wrapT: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    stencilBuffer: false,
    depthBuffer: true
  })
  
  renderTarget.texture.generateMipmaps = false
  renderTarget.setSize(w, h)

  return renderTarget
}

function swapBuffers () {
  const temp = previousTarget;
  previousTarget = resultTarget;
  resultTarget = temp;
}

function setMainScene () {
  renderer.setSize(w, h)
  renderer.setClearColor(0x111111)
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  camera.position.set(0, 20, 100);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());

  shape = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(10, 20, 20),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000 })
  );
  scene.add(shape);
}

function renderFrame (timeElapsed) {
  timeElapsed *= 0.001;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera, sceneTarget);
  
  blendMaterial.uniforms.tDiffuse1.value = previousTarget.texture;
  blendMaterial.uniforms.tDiffuse2.value = sceneTarget.texture;
  renderer.render(blendScene, blendCamera, resultTarget);
  
  resultMaterial.map = resultTarget.texture;
  renderer.render(resultScene, resultCamera);
  swapBuffers();

  shape.position.x = Math.sin(timeElapsed) * 20.0;
  shape.position.y = Math.cos(timeElapsed * Math.PI) * 20.0;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
  
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
```

Let me also add that's not really a good persistence affect. I'm not sure what the best one is. The problem with the one above is the higher you set the persistence the less you see of the current frame.

A better one, though it requires choosing a fade out color, would be something like this. Only 2 targets needed, `previousTarget` and `currentTarget`

1. Render `previousTarget.texture` to `currentTarget` with a shader
   that fades to a certain color. `mix(tex, color, 0.05)` or something like that.
2. Render the scene to `currentTarget` as well
3. Render `currentTarget.texture` to canvas
4. Swap `currentTarget` and `previousTarget`

```js
let w = window.innerWidth
let h = window.innerHeight

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, w / h, 0.1, 1000)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
const clock = new THREE.Clock()

let currentTarget = createRenderTarget()
let previousTarget  = currentTarget.clone();

const fadeScene = new THREE.Scene();
const fadeCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2, -1000, 1000);
const fadeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    tDiffuse: { value: previousTarget.texture },
  },
  vertexShader: `
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main () {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

      vUv = uv;
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main () {
      vec4 fadeColor = vec4(0,0,0,1);
      gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(tDiffuse, vUv), fadeColor, 0.05);
    }
  `,
});
const fadeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(w, h),
  fadeMaterial
);
fadeMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI;
fadeScene.add(fadeMesh);

const resultScene = new THREE.Scene();
const resultCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2, -1000, 1000);
const resultMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: currentTarget.texture,
});
const resultMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(w, h),
  resultMaterial
);
resultMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI;
resultScene.add(resultMesh);

let shape

setMainScene()
renderFrame(0)

function createRenderTarget () {
  let type = THREE.FloatType
  if( renderer.extensions.get( 'OES_texture_float_linear' ) === null ) type = THREE.HalfFloatType

  let renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 1, 1, {
    type,
    wrapS: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    wrapT: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    minFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter,
    stencilBuffer: false,
    depthBuffer: true
  })
  
  renderTarget.texture.generateMipmaps = false
  renderTarget.setSize(w, h)

  return renderTarget
}

function swapBuffers () {
  const temp = previousTarget;
  previousTarget = currentTarget;
  currentTarget = temp;
}

function setMainScene () {
  renderer.setSize(w, h)
  renderer.setClearColor(0x111111)
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio || 1)
  renderer.autoClearColor = false;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  camera.position.set(0, 20, 100);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());

  shape = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(10, 20, 20),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000 })
  );
  scene.add(shape);
}

function renderFrame (timeElapsed) {
  timeElapsed *= 0.001;
  
  fadeMaterial.uniforms.tDiffuse.value = previousTarget.texture;
  renderer.render(fadeScene, fadeCamera, currentTarget);
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera, currentTarget);
    
  resultMaterial.map = currentTarget.texture;
  renderer.render(resultScene, resultCamera);
  swapBuffers();

  shape.position.x = Math.sin(timeElapsed) * 20.0;
  shape.position.y = Math.cos(timeElapsed * Math.PI) * 20.0;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
  
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a ton, @gman! super helpful as always, i think i finally understand the technique!